# Python - How to get confidence interval in Keras models?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, confidence-interval

I currently have a Keras LSTM model set up for a timeseries forecast. I have made fitted data to the model and made some predictions. I have also outputted the RMSE values (if that helps).

How do I calculate the confidence interval for my prediction? Thank you.

```
def fit_model(train, batch_size, num_epochs, neurons):
  X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
  X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
  for i in range(num_epochs):
      model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
      model.reset_states()
  return model

error_scores = list()
repeats = 5
for r in range(repeats):
    # fit the model
    batch_size = 1
    epochs = 200
    model = fit_model(train_scaled, batch_size, epochs, neurons)
    # forecast the entire training dataset to build up state for forecasting
    train_reshaped = train_scaled[:, 0].reshape(len(train_scaled), 1, 1)
    model.predict(train_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
    # forecast test dataset
    test_reshaped = test_scaled[:, 0].reshape(len(test_scaled), 1, 1)
    output = model.predict(test_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
    predictions = list()
    for i in range(len(output)):
        # make one-step forecast
        yhat = output[i,0]
        X = test_scaled[i, 0:-1]
        # invert scaling
        yhat = invert_scale(scaler, X, yhat)
        # invert differencing
        yhat = inverse_difference_series(raw_values, yhat, len(test_scaled)+1-i)
        # store forecast
        predictions.append(yhat)
   
      rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(raw_values[-80:], predictions))
      print('%d) Test RMSE: %.3f' % (r+1, rmse))
      error_scores.append(rmse)
```

Comment: If you want to see how certain your model are in its predictions, then you should pick the Bayesian approach. That model is completely deterministic, you need a probabilistic model.

Comment: @Frightera Is there a stackoverflow/github repo with code you would recommend for me to look into in order to do this? I'm currently looking at a TDS article "Bayesian Neural Networks (LSTM): implementation" and "Probabilistic Bayesian Neural Networks" Experiment 2 on Keras' website. Is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes that are the probabilistic models.

Comment: @Frightera In the Keras example (Experiment 2 and 3), the author used a sample of 10 from the test dataset (85:15 split with total dataset size of 4898) with reasoning "We take a sample from the test set use the model to obtain predictions for them.". Thus, the mean, stddev, upper and lower CI are of length 10. Could you elaborate on why 10 was chosen? Can/should this sample be increased if I want to obtain CI for **all** my predictions.

Comment: I think 10 was chosen because it would be easy to compute, it can be done for whole data. Probabilistic Bayesian Neural Networks will behave as an ensemble network.

Comment: @Frightera In that case, 10 can be replaced with (4898*0.15=735 i.e. the length of his test data) and it would be correct?

Comment: Yes that would be correct as you get whole data from the dataset.

Comment: @Frightera Maybe I'm not understanding what they're doing (last code snippet and output of the Keras example). I'm not sure if they are creating a CI for each step of the prediction. If I apply it to my time series, will the output be such that it's predicted t, predicted t+1... and so on?

Alternatively, I have read that another viable way to add CI is by adding a dropout layer in the model. Then repeatedly run this model several times (which will yield a different output) and thus I can calculate the mean and variance from it? Does this sound correct?

Comment: Is not RMSE enough? What it’s say is that your models error is between plus or minus that Error

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel My RMSE is calculated at the very end using my predictions and actual targets. That should be for the whole model. I was hoping to get a confidence interval for each of the prediction points.

Comment: @Knovolt I missed that notification now I noticed that. Adding dropout is way to measure epistemic uncertainty however it won't be like a true Bayesian Model. It should work as you expect if you run it enough times, because priors in bayesian model will behave as a regularizer. It sounds correct because the network outcomes will behave as an ensemble like a Bayesian model

Comment: @Frightera No problem. I'm not sure if the implementation done is correct. I use the test set to make predictions with the MC dropout (running it through many iterations). Then, each of the predictions are looked at individually and the mean and confidence intervals are calculated from that. The doubt comes in when I see that the upper and lower CI are very, very close to each other. Like `y_true=1.821`, `y_pred=1.962`, `RMSE=0.099`, `99% CI=(1.71, 2.22)`. They are hardly distinguishable when plotted. Does this seem fine (it's even closer if I use a 95% CI) or does it depend on the data?

Comment: Implementation sounds correct, the values depend on data and the network itself. I'd go with 95% CI. If you have enough data then epistemic uncertainty should be low.

Comment: [Probabilistic Bayesian Neural Networks](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/bayesian_neural_networks/) - with confidence interval in Keras